# I want to retrieve the data to match values

Tags: python, django, mariadb

I want to retrieve the data to match username and password. So I try this but it doesn't work
Here my code in views.py

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
conn = mariadb.connect(host="localhost",user="django",password="1234",database="mydatabase")
cur = conn.cursor()
res = cur.execute("SELECT user_username FROM store_users WHERE user_username = username")
conn2 = mariadb.connect(host="localhost",user="django",password="1234",database="mydatabase")
cur2 = conn2.cursor()
res2 = cur2.execute("SELECT user_password FROM store_users WHERE user_password = password")
if res is not None and res2 is not None:
    return render(request,'index.html')
else:
    messages.error(request,"Username หรือ Password ไม่ถูกต้อง")
    return redirect("/login")
```

Comment: Hi. First of all Django is battery-included framework it have great authentication. Secondly the password is not (or at least should not) be stored as clear text. Passwords are salted and hashed. So you value from request.POST['password'] will never match.

Answer (score 0):

you should use F-strings for your queries:
F"SELECT user_username FROM store_users WHERE user_username = {username}"

Comment: it didn't work. ProgrammingError at /logincheck/
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '}' at line 1

Comment: what is your python version?